# Join two tables on all possible string matches

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables, Student and Reference.  I want to join student.code on Reference.ReferenceCode.  The issue is that Student can have multiple codes in a code column.  I would like to join in such a way that multiple lines are produced when there are multiple codes for a student in the student table.  Here's what I have and what I've tried:

Student has two columns: ID & Code

```
|Student ID   |Code             |
|Student1     |Code1            |
|Student2     |Code1,Code2,Code3|
```

ReferenceCode has two columns: ReferenceCode & Description

```
|ReferenceCode|Description      |
|Code1        |This is code 1   |
|Code2        |This is code 2   |
|Code3        |This is code 3   |
```

I've tried using Substring:

```
select a.studentID, a.code, b.ReferenceCode, b.Description
from Student a
left join Reference b --Have also tried inner join;  No difference
on b.ReferenceCode = substring(a.Code,1,len(b.ReferenceCode))
```

Substring produces the following table.  Note, that it only matches the first code:

```
|Student ID   |Code             |ReferenceCode    |Description    |
|Student1     |Code1            |Code1            |This is code 1 |
|Student2     |Code1,Code2,Code3|Code1            |This is code 1 |
```

I've also tried the *like* method:

```
select a.studentID, a.code, b.ReferenceCode, b.Description
from Student a
left join Reference b --Have also tried inner join;  No difference
on b.ReferenceCode like '%' + a.Code + '%'
```

But this method results in a table that only matches records in the student table that only have one code:

```
|Student ID   |Code             |ReferenceCode    |Description    |
|Student1     |Code1            |Code1            |This is code 1 |
*Student 2 doesn't pull*
```

What I want to see is this:

```
|Student ID   |Code             |ReferenceCode    |Description    |
|Student1     |Code1            |Code1            |This is code 1 |
|Student2     |Code1,Code2,Code3|Code1            |This is code 1 |
|Student2     |Code1,Code2,Code3|Code2            |This is code 2 |
|Student2     |Code1,Code2,Code3|Code3            |This is code 3 |
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, can you change the structure of the DB?  If you can, it would be worth the time to do so rather than to try and cater for the structure the way it currently is.

Comment: What @GrandMasterFlush is saying is that you have delimited values in a single column. This violates 1NF and makes queries far more painful than they should be. If you absolutely can't fix this then you need a string splitter. You can find a great article about this kind of thing here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush  This is something I really, really want to happen.  The problem is a business one - these are files that come from a vendor to us and waiting for a fix on their end would probably be slower than me coding my way through it.

Comment: Bad luck. I think most devs have been in that position before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are proposing will have significant performance problems. Are you able to change the database schema? If so, the following is a much better approach.

You are defining a many-to-many mapping. To correctly map this, you would need a separate "mapping" table that contains only the ids from the student and reference code tables.

So your new schema would look like this:

**Student table**

```
| Student ID (int) |
| 1                |
| 2                |
```

**StudentCode table**

```
| StudentId (int) | ReferenceCodeId (int) |
| 1               | 1                     |
| 2               | 1                     |
| 2               | 2                     |
| 2               | 3                     |
```

**ReferenceCode table**

```
|ReferenceCodeId (int) | Description     | 
|1                     |This is code 1   |
|2                     |This is code 2   |
|3                     |This is code 3   |
```

Then your query would look something like this:

```
select s.StudentId, rc.Description 
from Student s 
left join StudentCode sc on s.StudentId = sc.StudentId
left join ReferenceCode rc on sc.ReferenceCodeId = rc.ReferenceCodeId
```

And your results would look like this:

```
|StudentId| Description     | 
|1        |This is code 1   |
|2        |This is code 1   |
|2        |This is code 2   |
|2        |This is code 3   |
```

A quick search for "sql many to many relationship" should provide you with significant reference material.

Comment: Thanks Francisco.  This looks like the route I will have to take.  I appreciate the extra search material.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inline user defined function that produces a column of rows (a row for each comma delimited value) - then you will be able to join to that column.

That kind of functions would often have code that replaces the delimiter with XML tags and then selects from the XML,it can also be CLR or a number of other approaches. You can find some stuff in [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), there you will find different approaches and performance comparison results.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I may be combining this strategy with one mentioned in another response and reorganizing the data files that come through to my office.  Appreciate the extra reading material.